# Can I accept the null hypothesis?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, anova

I'm running an ANOVA on some data that I have. I get that if my p-value is less than 0.05 (with a significance of 5%) I can reject the null hypothesis and accept that the means between my groups are different, but that doesn't seem to be the case in my data, in fact, the p-value is greater than 0.95. Does this mean that I can, with statistical significance, accept the hypothesis that the means of my groups are equal?

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85903/why-do-statisticians-say-a-non-significant-result-means-you-cant-reject-the-nu

Comment: @BruceET the assumptions are correct and I think this is expected. We are trying to determine the factors that affect our data, and what I'm trying to show is that this factor, in particular, is not one of them. Basically, I'm doubting the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. Basically the alternative hypothesis is what you want to prove. Thus you assume the Null hypothesis unless there is a significant reason to believe otherwise.

For this one intruduces the error of first order and the error of second order. The error of first order is basically: How big is the probability that if the Nullhypothesis is in fact true we are rejecting it. And the error of second order is: How big is the probability that if the Nullhypothis is not true we are not rejecting it.

One then constructs a test in such a way that the error of first order is lower than some threshold.

Now, the $p$-value is basically: What is the largest threshold so that I would just reject the nullhypothesis. So if your $p$-value is $0.95$ that if the Nullhypothesis is true you’d expect to get something as extreme as your result in 95% of the cases.

But if you want to turn around the whole thing you’d need to make the error of second order small.

EDIT: You might want to look into the so called *power* of a test, which is the counterprobability to the error of second order. Basically the power says: If the alternative hypothesis is true, how likely is it that we’ll determine this correctly to be.

Even if the $p$-value is high that does not mean that the power is high.